# sendmail port error at MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, email, smtp, sendmail

Kindly, I have the mentioned error for this code:

```
username='XXX@hotmail.com';
pass='XXXXX';
port=465;   % hotmail
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');    
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class','javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port',port);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.hotmail.com');
setpref('Internet','E_mail',username);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',username);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',pass);
sendmail(username,'Available');
```

**Error:**

*No method 'setProperty' with matching signature found for class 'java.util.Properties'.*

*Error in*

`props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port',port);`

Any support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port', '465' )
```

or

```
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port', num2str(port) )
```

. This works for me. It seems that a string is expected but you are passing a numerical value.

Comment: Many Thanks but I have got another error:

`Error using sendmail (line 171)

Unknown SMTP host: mail.smtp.hotmail.com;

mail.smtp.hotmail.com`
_Error in XXX_
`sendmail(username,'Available');`